# postgreSQL - How to have condition on Join model result

Tags: sql, postgresql, inner-join, aggregate-functions, having-clause

I have been pulling my hair on how to translate my business requirement into a SQL query.

The case in itself is not that complex. I have two main tables `user` and `list` and a many to many relationship between the 2 of them though the `userList` table, where a user can be connected to a list by having a specific role, like being the owner or a collaborator.

Relevant properties for that example:

```
user     -> id 
list     -> id | isPublic (BOOL)
userList -> id | userId | listId | role (OWNER|COLLABORATOR)
```

I have an API endpoint that allows for a user (requester) to retrieve all the lists of another user (target). I have the following 2 cases:

**Case 1**: requester = target

I have that under control with:

```
`SELECT
  "list".*,
  "userList"."id" AS "userList.id",
  "userList"."listId" AS "userList.listId"
FROM
  "list" AS "list"
INNER JOIN 
  "userList" AS "userList"
  ON "list"."id" = "userList"."listId" AND "userList"."userId" = '${targetUserId}'`;
```

**Case 2**: requester =/= target

This is where I'm stuck as I have the following additional constraints:

- a user can only see other users' lists that are public
- OR lists for which they have the role of `COLLABORATOR` or `OWNER`

So I'm looking to do something like:
Get all the lists for which `target` is connected to (no matter the role) AND for which, EITHER the list is public OR the `requester` is also connected to that list.

**Sample Data**

```
user table

id
----------
john
anna

list table

id   | isPublic
------------------
1        false
2        true
3        false

userList table

id   |    userId    |  listId    |  role
-          john          1          OWNER
-          john          2          OWNER
-          john          3          OWNER
-          anna          1          COLLABORATOR
```

Anna requests to see all of John's lists

desired result:

```
[{
   id: 1,
   isPublic: false
}, {
   id: 2,
   isPublic: true
}]
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated :)

Many thanks

Comment: Sample data and desired results would help.

Comment: @GordonLinoff edited with requested info; let me know if it still misses clarity

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Does this do what you want?

```
select l.*
from list
inner join userlist ul on ul.listid = l.id
group by l.id
having 
    bool_or(ul.role = 'OWNER' and ul.userid = 'john')  -- owned by John
    and (l.ispublic or bool_or(ul.userid = 'anna')     -- public or allowed to Anna
```

Comment: Works great :) I'm a bit confused with the group by in the results; how would I be able to also have the join info from userList table?